# Nginx support multiple hostnames

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am working on my django + nginx + docker-compose project
I want to access my site via ip and `mysite.com`

**Problem** -- ip url is working, but `mysite.com` returns error:

> 403 Forbidden Nginx

My code - docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  django:
    build: ./project # path to Dockerfile
    command: sh -c " 
      sleep 3 && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core_app.wsgi"
    ...
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    depends_on: 
      - django
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./project/nginx-conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      ...
```

**nginx-conf.conf**

```
upstream app {
    server django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/html/static/;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was trying to replace `proxy_pass http://django:8000;` with `proxy_pass http://app;` but it didn't help

Comment: Can you attach Django settings `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: Thank you, allowed hosts were OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `proxy_pass` is incorrect.

When you're referencing an `upstream` group, you've to pass the **name of the group** to `proxy_pass`.

In your case, the name of upstream group is **"app"**. So the value of `proxy_pass` should look like this:

```
proxy_pass http://app;
```

Comment: Thank you, 
updated my nginx file, but I still have this error (403 Forbidden)
https://content-protect.mgns-tech.ru/

Comment: @mascai Did you also reload nginx?

Comment: I rebuilt docker compose ```docker-compose up --build```